# How to display a JSON in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to output the results from a JSON file into a table. I created some filters, by field type, to make the user's search easier. Maybe I'll narrow down the search fields. But the problem is that the data is not being visualized in the HTML page I created.
It's not clear to me where I'm going wrong

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**HTML(Just the part that should show the data)**

```
<head>
    <title>Page Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/5.2.0/morph/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="tablesearch.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="myInput" onkeyup="searchTable(this.value, 'list')"
                    placeholder="Buscar en la tabla completa..." title="Search">
                <input type="text" class="myInput" onkeyup="searchTable(this.value, 'list', 0)"
                    placeholder="Seleccionar por país..." title="Search">
                <input type="text" class="myInput" onkeyup="searchTable(this.value, 'list', 1)"
                    placeholder="Seleccionar por ciudad..." title="Search">
                <input type="text" class="myInput" onkeyup="searchTable(this.value, 'list', 2)"
                    placeholder="Seleccionar por cuenta..." title="Search">

                <table id="list" class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>País</th>
                            <th>Ciudad</th>
                            <th>Cuenta</th>
                            <th>URL</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="stats-output">

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

**JS (script.js)**

```
fetch("contas.json")
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (contas) {
        let placeholder = document.querySelector("#stats-output");
        let out = "";
        for (let conta of contas) {
            out += `
            <tr>
                <td>${conta.Country_Code}</td>
                <td>${conta.Account_City}</td>
                <td>${conta.Account_Name}</td>
                <td> <a href="${conta.Account_Link}"> Clic aquí </td>
            </tr>
        `;
        }

        placeholder.innerHTML = out;
    });
```

**Table Search JS**

PS.: Just for information, because I believe the filters will work correctly.
If I create something like below the filter works correctly

```
<tr>
   <td>AR</td>
   <td>Ciudad</td>
   <td>Cuenta</td>
   <td>Encuesta Link</td>
</tr>
```

```
function searchTable(input, tableId, searchColumn = -1, searchColumn2 = -1, searchColumn3 = -1) 
{
    var filter = input.toUpperCase();
    var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    var rowText, rowText2, rowText3;    //temporary var
    
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        //iterate through rows
        if (searchColumn == -1) //by default, search all columns
        {
            if (i != 0) {   //don't perform search on the first row header
                rowText = row.innerHTML;    //get text for the whole row
                if (rowText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {   //if upper case matches any part of filter
                    row.style.display = "";
                }
                else {
                    row.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (i != 0) {   //don't perform search on the first row header

                if (searchColumn3 != -1) {  //3 category search
                    rowText = row.cells[searchColumn].innerHTML;    //get text for the 1st column
                    rowText2 = row.cells[searchColumn2].innerHTML;  //get text for the 2nd column
                    rowText3 = row.cells[searchColumn3].innerHTML;  //get text for the 3rd column
                    if (rowText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || rowText2.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || rowText3.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { //if upper case matches any part of filter
                        row.style.display = "";
                    }
                    else {
                        row.style.display = "none";
                    }   
                    
                }           
                else if (searchColumn2 != -1) { //2 category search
                    rowText = row.cells[searchColumn].innerHTML;    //get text for the 1st column
                    rowText2 = row.cells[searchColumn2].innerHTML;  //get text for the 2nd column
                    if (rowText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || rowText2.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {    //if upper case matches any part of filter
                        row.style.display = "";
                    }
                    else {
                        row.style.display = "none";
                    }   
                    
                }
                else {  //single category search
                    rowText = row.cells[searchColumn].innerHTML;    //get text for the whole row
                    if (rowText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {   //if upper case matches any part of filter
                        row.style.display = "";
                    }
                    else {
                        row.style.display = "none";
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }

        /*
        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        //iterate through columns (optional)
        }  
        */
    }
    
}
```

**Example to work with data**

[manually data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Esc.png)

[try with json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOLi9.png)

**JSON - data example (contas.json)**

```
[
  {
    "Account_ID": "00000000000QAI",
    "Account_Name": "Test Test",
    "Country_Code": "AR",
    "Account_City": "25 de Mayo",
    "Form_Link": "https://test.com",
    "ID_Link": "?AccountID=00000000000QAI",
    "Account_Link": "https://test.com?AccountID=00000000000QAI"
  },
```

Regarding

Thanks for attention

Can view the results of a Json file in an HTML page

Comment: Have you added console.log or debugger statements to verify the code is running? Are there any errors in the developer console?

Comment: Have you made sure the JSON path is not wrong?

Comment: Re edit: Please address epascarallo's question. I wouldn't be surprised i you were hitting the common error of trying to `fetch` a local (i.e. not any kind of HTTP) URL but if you were the developer tools console would be telling you that (and you seem to not even be looking at it).

Comment: Hi @epascarello. I did not put. I updated the question by adding 2 images. See the comparison when I enter the data manually and when I try to integrate with json. I thought that indicating where the data comes from would work. I'll put the console to check

Comment: The point of adding logging is to tell you what is happening in the middle. Looking only at the source code and pictures of the rendered webpage only tells you what it happening at the *ends*. Sometimes you have to work with a black box (and it is horrible and time consuming), this isn't one of those times!

Comment: Hi @Quentin
Thanks for clarification.Now I see.

Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\aland\Downloads\Trade\script.js:1:1)
    --- Promise.then ---
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\aland\Downloads\Trade\script.js:5:6)

Comment: There's probably another error message that tells you *why* it failed to fetch.

Comment: Ow sorry I forgot the last line
"No debugger available, can not send 'variables'"

Comment: You really should run a local dev server and not run off the local file system. Sounds like your JSON file is not where it is.